# Trying to read data from JSON file - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I'm trying to read off some of my FitBit data for a project I'm working on in class.
The file is a JSON, which I've never worked with before. I'm trying to read it using Python, but I keep getting thrown errors.

I'm able to convert the data into a python dictionary, but I'm struggling to separate out the values I want. I'm trying to select out all the values following 'bpm' so that I can build an array out of them.

The output I'm receiving is:

```
========== RESTART: C:\Users\Addy\Physical Activity\JSON Import.py ==========
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Addy\Physical Activity\JSON Import.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in data['values']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I understand why I'm getting it, and I've seen other examples where people search for items by their integer value instead, but I don't think that really helps me.

Here's what I have so far, along with the data I'm trying to read:

```
import json 
  
# Opening JSON file 
f = open('/Users/Addy/Physical Activity/heart_rate-2020-10-06.json',)
  
# returns JSON object as  
# a dictionary

data = json.loads(f.read()) 
  
# Iterating through the json 
# list 
for i in data['values']: 
    print(i)

f.close() 
  
print(data)
```

```
 [{'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:01', 'value': {'bpm': 69, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:11', 'value': {'bpm': 68, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:21', 'value': {'bpm': 70, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:26', 'value': {'bpm': 71, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:31', 'value': {'bpm': 72, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:05:46', 'value': {'bpm': 73, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:06:01', 'value': {'bpm': 76, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:06:06', 'value': {'bpm': 75, 'confidence': 1}}, {'dateTime': '10/06/20 20:06:16', 'value': {'bpm': 72, 'confidence': 1}}]
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the output you are showing. As it stands, you should have got a different error.

Comment: Data is a list, so it has no keys. Thus, you cannot access the `'values'` key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is `list` of `dicts`, then value for key `value` is again `dict` and you want value for key `bpm`.

```
import json 

with open('/Users/Addy/Physical Activity/heart_rate-2020-10-06.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f) 

bpm = [item['value']['bpm'] for item in data]
print(bpm)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I realized I was working with a nested dictionary-dictionary-list a few minute before seeing your post, but wasn't sure how to approach it. This did exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a list, not a dictionary so you can just use

```py
for i in data: 
    print(i)
```